# Tradução da mensagem de aviso de levantado feito pelo Comunidade♦

Tags: suporte, tradução

Recentemente foi adicionada uma mensagem de aviso nas perguntas que o perfil bot Comunidade♦ "sobe" na página principal, porém, a mesma está em inglês:

<kbd>[image: mensagem em inglês]</kbd>

link do exemplo da imagem: [Navegar entre telas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/73208/navegar-entre-telas)

Comment: Alguém sugere tradução para *bumped*?

Comment: @bigown A pergunta foi ("projetada", "levantada", "levada") para a página (mae, inicial) pela comunidade.

Comment: Acho que poderíamos colocar respostas com sugestões de tradução, daí o pessoal votava na que acharem mais apropriadas. Essa daí não é fácil não... Cc @BrunoCosta

Comment: @Math ótima ideia :)

Comment: Eu conheço por "ressuscitar pergunta" hahaha, mas não sei se ficaria bom no stackoverflow.

Comment: "Pergunta _escavada_ pela comunidade" :D

Answer (score 9):

> **Pergunta levada para a página principal por Comunidade♦ x mins atrás**
>
> Esta pergunta possui respostas que podem ser boas ou ruins; o sistema a marcou como ativa para que possam ser revistas.

Comment: Como disse nos comentários da minha resposta tem que fazer concordancia de número (so that they). Quem deve ser revisado ou revistas) devem ser as respostas(mais que uma possivelmente) e nao a pergunta. Ou até mesmo ambos

Comment: @BrunoCosta nossa, agora entendi ahuahua.. vou revisar

Comment: @BrunoCosta optei por deixar ambíguo na minha.. vamo ver o que dizem

Comment: A mim tanto me dá mesmo, desde que esteja minimamente correto, como está agora +1

Comment: Não seria mais trazida que levada?

Comment: @bfavaretto eu cheguei a pensar em trazida ao invés de levada, mas pensei que depois de um tempo quando ela não estiver mais no topo a mensagem ficaria estranha. O que acha?

Comment: Imaginei que o aviso sumiria depois de algumas horas. Mas ainda não sei como funciona.

Comment: Também não sei como funciona isso ainda

Comment: @Math essa foi a mais votada, ja pode ser aplicada ne?

Comment: @diegofm acredito que sim, já mandei para o transifex, falta o Gabe aprovar e sair uma nova release do site

Comment: @diegofm foi para o ar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/127705/uml-especifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-caso-de-uso

Answer (score 4):

> **Pergunta promovida à página principal por Comunidade♦ x mins atrás**
>
> As respostas a esta pergunta podem ser boas ou ruins. O sistema marcou esse conteúdo como ativo para que possa ser revisto.

Comment: Eu ia votar mas não gostei do "para a home" mas gosto do "pormovida". Não gostas mais de "para a página principal"?

Comment: Concordo com o @JorgeB. quanto ao título. Já a explicação acho que tá boa assim.

Comment: @jorge Eu prefiro home por ser mais curto. Não funciona em Portugal?

Comment: Funciona, mas prefiro a variante em português. É mais clara.

Comment: @JorgeB. Alterado nas minhas 3 respostas

Answer (score 1):

> **Pergunta destacada na página principal por Comunidade♦ x mins atrás**
>
> As respostas a esta pergunta podem ser boas ou ruins. O sistema marcou esse conteúdo como ativo para que possa ser revisto.

Answer (score 1):

> **Pergunta reapresentada na página principal por Comunidade♦ x mins atrás**
>
> As respostas a esta pergunta podem ser boas ou ruins. O sistema marcou esse conteúdo como ativo para que possa ser revisto.

Comment: Gostei mais dessa por causa do "reapresentada", me parece mais condizente com o que acontece de fato. Não vejo bem como um "destaque" pq fica igual a todas as outras, e nem como promoção, pq geralmente é pra "consertar" algo e não pra dizer "olha que legal!"

Comment: Também gosto da precisão dessa, mas por outro lado fica mais formal

Comment: Nem faço questão de formal, pra ser sincero. Mas um informal que não corresponde ao fato pra mim não dá, mesmo que fique "lindo" :)

Comment: Bom, já que essa aqui tomou 2 negativos, tou negativando o resto que eu não gostei só pra refletir a realidade, assim as opções fica representadas "na mesma moeda", muita gente não tem pontos pra ver o score "dividido"